# How to apply evolutions manually and mark as resolved on play framework 2

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, playframework-evolutions

Is it to possible mark evolutions as applied in playframework 2?

Scenario: I had to change an already applied evolution file because it was incompatible with H2 causing the remaining evolutions not to be applied during tests. So, I fixed it. Now the application wants to reapply the modified evolutions. I want to just "mark resolved" without applying (and avoid drop to recreate the tables.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apply the evolutions locally, dump the whole table `play_evolutions` and restore into the production database. See the comment of @biesior to understand why we need all fields.

Comment: As I can see, this approach can work, but you need to copy whole `play_evoulutions` record from local to remote as it checking also checksum from apply_script. Anyway start with backup

Comment: Your suggestion worked. Put It in a answer so I can accept it.

Comment: It was your suggestion :), so add my comment to your answer, add some formatting and accept it in next 2 days :)